# "IllegalArgumentException: invalid column begin" when trying to get Event in Android

Tags: android, events, calendar, uri

I'm using the following code to get all the calendars and get the first event in each.
But when I execute the query it fails.
I'm using the following URI:
`Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/instances/when").buildUpon();`
I've checked and I get the correct list of the calendars ID's, here is the query code :

```
Cursor eventCursor = null;
// Create an event cursor to find all events in the calendar
try {
    eventCursor = contentResolver.query(builder.new String[]  { "title", "begin", "end", "allDay"}, "Calendars._id=" + 1, null, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC");
    Log.d(TAG,"Got Calendar ID = "+id);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Didn't find calender for ID="+id);
    eventCursor = null;
}
```

I get the following error from the SQL : `illegalargumentexception invalid column begin`
I googled this error and found nothing, plus, I saw all queries of this kind uses this exact columns and get succeed.

Comment: Does your database have a column named `"begin"`?

Comment: Sorry, see edit, I've used `Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/instances/when").buildUpon();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing **null** in the begin column.

```
   eventCursor = contentResolver.query(builder.new String[]  { "title", "begin", "end", "allDay"}, "Calendars._id=" + 1, null, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC");
```

Comment: I changed it, now I get there is no column called `Calendars._id`

Comment: OK, the error was since for API >= 7 , the correct column is `calendar_id`.

Answer (score 3):

You have given wrong arguments in query() method. Here is some sample code:

final ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
final String[] projection = { People._ID, People.NAME, People.NUMBER };
final String sa1 = "%A%"; // contains an "A"
cursor = resolver.query(People.CONTENT_URI, projection, People.NAME + " LIKE ?",
   new String[] { sa1 }, null);

check this link for more detail: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String%29